# Using scala.collection.immutable.Map inside my java class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-8

I get bellow exception from my java codes.

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
    at au.com.vroc.udf.medianUDF.update(medianUDF.java:79)
```

I am getting error in my spark application when I cast the buffer to HashMap of java.utill. This is my codes:

```
    public void update(MutableAggregationBuffer buffer, Row input) {
    if (!input.isNullAt(0)) {   

        HashMap currentBuffer=(HashMap) buffer.get(0);//getting exception here
        //HashMap currentBuffer=new HashMap();  
        currentBuffer.put(input.getLong(0), input.getDouble(0));

        //currentBuffer.add(currentMap);

        buffer.update(0, currentBuffer);

    }
}
```

I guess instead of java hashmap I have to use "scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1" inside my java class. Can I use any tool in "JavaConversions" namespace.

Anyhep would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach would likely be to use [Scala Converters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html).

It should look something like this (not tested, but type-checks):

```
import scala.collections.JavaConverters

java.util.Map currentBuffer = JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter(buffer.get(0)).asJava();
```

Please note that it returns type-parameterized map (i.e. `java.util.Map<K, V>`), not the non-parameterized `java.util.HashMap`in your example - you might want to alter the rest of your code to work on the parameterized maps for better type safety.

Comment: Upvoted, but it is not necessary. There is  getJavaMap method which applies conversions automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You get `java.util.Map` you should use [`getJavaMap` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getJavaMap-int-):

```
java.util.Map<T, U> currentBuffer = (java.util.Map<T, U>) first.getJavaMap(0)
```

Note that this is not `HashMap` - initialized value is `Encoded` on `update` and decoded on `get`. To modify it, you have to make a copy.